# SAP UI5: Formating of the viz.frame diagram on x-Axis

Tags: sapui5

i'm currently trying the HCP with sensortag. 
Sensortag sends every 60s the temperature to HCP and diagram works well.
Only problem is, that i only see the last 30 values in the diagram, as the timestamp is the value for axis.

1. which possibilites are there to format the diagram ? can i sum up these data values so the x-axis is shown per hour f.e. ?
2. is it also possible to add for example a second line for each day.
   That means, data points with color 1 shows temperature for day1, color 2 for day 2 etc. and x-Axis shows the hours from 0-24

---

edit:
ok, got it to format the hour from the x-axis with this code:

```
Axis : { scale: { fixedRange : true, minValue : "0:00", maxValue : "24:00" } } –
```

so Point 2. remains open, how can i format measures?

```
measures: [
        {
            name: "C_SENSORTEMP",
            value: "{C_SENSORTEMP}"
        },
        {
            name: "C_SENSORHUMIDITY",
            value: "{C_SENSORHUMIDITY}"
        }

    ],
```

Thanks all

```
var vizFrame = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame("graph").addStyleClass("sapUiSmallMarginBegin").addStyleClass("sapUiSmallMarginTop");
    vizFrame.setWidth("900px");
    var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
        dimensions: [
            {
                name: "Date",
                value: {
                    path: "G_CREATED",
                    formatter: function(val){
                        if (val == null) {
                            return "string null";
                        }                           
                        var date = new Date(parseInt(val.substr(6,20)));
                        var dd = date.getDate();
                        var mm = date.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
                        var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
                        var hr = date.getHours();
                        var min = date.getMinutes();
                        var sec = date.getSeconds();
                        var fromdate1 = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy + " " + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
                        return fromdate1;
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        measures: [
            {
                name: "C_SENSORTEMP",
                value: "{C_SENSORTEMP}"
            },
            {
                name: "C_SENSORHUMIDITY",
                value: "{C_SENSORHUMIDITY}"
            }

        ],
        data: {
            path: "/items"

        }
    });
    vizFrame.setDataset(oDataset);
    vizFrame.setVizType('line');

    vizFrame.setVizProperties({
        plotArea: {
            colorPalette :  ["#5cbae6", "#b6d957", "#fac364"]
            },
        categoryAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "Date/Time"
            }
        },
        valueAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "temp/humidity"
            }
        },
        title: {
            visible:false
        }
    });

    var feedValueAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
          'uid': "valueAxis",
          'type': "Measure",
          'values': ["C_SENSORTEMP", "C_SENSORHUMIDITY"]
        }), 
        feedCategoryAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
          'uid': "categoryAxis",
          'type': "Dimension",
          'values': ["Date"]
        });

    vizFrame.addFeed(feedValueAxis);
    vizFrame.addFeed(feedCategoryAxis);

    var container = new sap.m.VBox({
        items: [vizFrame],
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        alignItems: "Center"
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is solved:

1) got a limitation of 30 datasets in the omodel

2) xAxis-scale values:

```
 yAxis : {scale: {
                              fixedRange : true,
                              minValue : "15",
                              maxValue : "30"
                    }},
```

categories / groups for each date in colors:

```
var oDataset = new sap.viz.ui5.data.FlattenedDataset({
dimensions: [{
name: "hour",value: "{hour}"},
name: "date", value: "{date}"}
...
var feedValueAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
          'uid': "valueAxis",
          'type': "Measure",
          'values': ["SENSORTEMP"]
        }), 
        feedCategoryAxis = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
          'uid': "categoryAxis",
          'type': "Dimension",
          'values': ["hour"]
        }),
        feedColor = new sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds.FeedItem({
            "uid": "color",
            "type": "Dimension",
            "values": ["date"]
 });
```